# select * into outfile not working even for root

Tags: mysql, linux, select, into-outfile

When I run

```
mysql> select * into outfile "/home/akihirom/file1.txt" from BAIT_INTERACTION;
```

I get the following error:

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/akihirom/file1.txt' (Errcode: 13)

This happens even as root, in mysql or on the system itself. Does anyone know why this may be happening?  Thanks

Comment: Is there a typo in `/home/akihirom`? If the directory doesn't exist, it can't create a file there.

Comment: @gpojd It's Errcode 13 which means permission denied.

Comment: Probably because mysqld is running as user mysql instead of root. Try writing it to /tmp to see if the problem persists. If it does, you know what to look for.

Comment: Jon sudo did not fix the issue, gpojd pretty sure that the path does not contain a typo, Friek I will give that a try thanks

Comment: run it under strace to see exactly what's happening on opening `/home/akihirom/file1.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do the same thing using mysql dump by dumping the contents of the select statement to a file:

```
mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE --execute='SELECT `FIELD`, `FIELD` FROM `TABLE` LIMIT 0, 10000 ' -X > file.xml
```

[Where I got the idea from](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/mysql-182/using-mysqldump-export-individual-fields-599062.html)

Answer (score 2):

I merged both examples into one and came up with the following that I used for a capistrano task.  I was able to invoke a shell and run this from the command line.

```
mysql -uUSERNAME --database=${DBNAME} --execute=" SELECT * FROM ${TBNAME} INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dumps/DBNAME.out' "
```

I added spacing before double quotes so you could see syntax differences.

Answer (score 0):

Respect to   ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/akihirom/file1.txt' (Errcode: 13)
  use only ' file1.txt' because server only writes on /var/lib/mysql/DB   (where DB is a directory named as the data base) and later if you are root, go to there and manage the file as your needs.
You can use file1.cvs too; it works the same as file1.txt