# How to i export Mysql Data to excel?

Tags: mysql, excel

How do i export mysql table data to microsoft excel?

is there  a way to write a query to output this data?

i am assuming the query should take the form

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename
OUTPUT INTO SOMEFILE.xls;
```

kindly help

Comment: that post doesn't resolve this error ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/inventor/ictbf.csv/' (Errcode: 21)

Comment: Then why don't you add to your question that you get this error? *sigh* See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209158/select-into-outfile-not-working-even-for-root
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile

Comment: I have managed to accomplish the task

SELECT *
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/root/tmp/myoutput.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in CSV format:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tablename
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: hi after trying your answer i encountered the following error

    ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file    '/home/inventor/ictbf.csv/' (Errcode: 21)

Comment: @Inventor make sure you have writing permission on the folder you trying to write to

Comment: thanks i have managed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can connect to the database using Excel and the just import the data using the specified query.

You can do this on the data tab of Excel. Assuming you have excel 2007 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some GUI clients like SQLyog or Navicat and export. SQLyog has [free version](https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list).